# Pandas: Dropping columns with 2 blank lines every time a series of 0 appear

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big chunk of data, with a lot of columns, but this columns present at some points 0. I want every time that a 0 appears in the column "two", that column to drop it with 2 blank lines.

```
one  two three 
1     4     4
3     5     5
5     7     5
666   0     6
785   0     8 
455   0     9 
454   0     9
12    2     8
23    5     9
2     3     7
1     5     5 
123   0     7 
123   0     7
3     5     5
 

(desired)
output:


one  two three 
1     4     4
3     5     5
5     7     5


12    2     8
23    5     9
2     3     7
1     5     5 


3     5     5
```

I tried different function: split, groupby, drop with conditions......., but noone didn't meet my request (most probably because I suck at coding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
m = df['two'].ne(0)

out = (df[m]
        .groupby((m & ~m.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum(), group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([g, pd.DataFrame('', columns=g.columns, index=[0, 1])]))
        .reset_index(drop=True)
      )

print(out.to_string(index=False))
```

Or with a hacky [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html):

```
N = 2

m1 = df['two'].ne(0)
m2 = (m1 & ~m1.shift(fill_value=True))
idx = df.index[m1].repeat(m2[m1]*N+1)

out = df.loc[idx]
out[out.index.duplicated()] = ''

print(out.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
one two three
  1   4     4
  3   5     5
  5   7     5
             
             
 12   2     8
 23   5     9
  2   3     7
  1   5     5
             
             
  3   5     5
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, and if I had somethingh like the number with decimal ? I have another file  with  a sequence of 0 and than it start with 0,0004;  0,13;   0,15. But in this case  the block ends with a number like 0,xxx instead with the supposed one.

Comment: Then I guess you could maybe use `m = df['two'].between(0, 1, inclusive='left')`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

`pd.Index.union()` has a `sort` option, so when reindexing, it should be in the correct order

```
m = df['two'].ne(0)
df.reindex(df.loc[m].index.union(df.loc[m.diff().ne(0) & ~m].index.repeat(2) + .5)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
     one  two  three
0    1.0  4.0    4.0
1    3.0  5.0    5.0
2    5.0  7.0    5.0
3    NaN  NaN    NaN
4    NaN  NaN    NaN
5   12.0  2.0    8.0
6   23.0  5.0    9.0
7    2.0  3.0    7.0
8    1.0  5.0    5.0
9    NaN  NaN    NaN
10   NaN  NaN    NaN
11   3.0  5.0    5.0
```